# Is there anyway to avoid redundant cleanups of photos across apple devices?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, photos, photos.app

If I take a picture on my iPhone, it shows up when I open up "Photos" app on my mac when I click on "Photos" in the upper left.  This integration is quite nice to avoid having to do a manual sync but it has created a bit of overhead and confusion.

In most cases I like to groom my photos to get rid of lots of fuzzy or duplicate pictures but since it seems like a copy of the photo on my mac, If I cleanup these bad pictures on my iPhone, i also have to clean then up on my mac.

First, I am trying to confirm that my mac has a "copy" of the picture (or a reference to the picture on the phone) and if I go and delete that picture on my phone, can I also get it to delete that picture on my mac.

Is this behavior configurable?

I am trying to find a balance between enjoying the integration of things showing in mac photos without me having to do a manual sync with the overhead of doing these redundant cleanups.

Answer (score 1):

If using iCloud sync, deleting a photo on one device will generate an alert notifying you that you are removing it from ALL of your devices, not just that one. You shouldn't have to worry about manually rectifying changes between devices.